# 誕生日が来たら、1分ごとにメッセージを切り替える記述の仕方

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、誕生日が来たらメッセージが表示され、誕生日が過ぎたら次の誕生日まで
デジタル時計が表示されるように設定されています。
これを、誕生日が来たら１分ごとにメッセージをa)とb)に切り替えるようにするには、
どうすればいいでしょうか。
偶数の分(〇%2==０)と奇数の分(〇%２==０+1)をうまく入れられません。

a) 偶数の分のメッセージ: 金さん銀さん 〇歳の誕生日おめでとう！！！！！
b) 奇数の分のメッセージ: 後で、プレゼントを送ります☆

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>


<style type="text/css">

/* Circle Text Styles */
#myText {
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
color: gold;

position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;}
#myText div {position: relative;}
#myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}
/* End Required */
/* End Circle Text Styles */
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

;(function(){

var birthday = new Date(1917, 3, 8);
var isBirthDay = false;

if((new Date().getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && (new Date().getDate() == birthday.getDate())) {
    var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
    var msg="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳"+"の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう！！！！！";
    isBirthDay = true;

} else {
  var ti = new Date;

     var Hour = ti.getHours();
     var Min = ti.getMinutes();
     var Sec = ti.getSeconds();

        if(Hour <= 9) { 
                       Hour = "\u0020\u0020" + Hour; 
}        
　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                       Min = "0" + Min; 
}
        if(Sec <= 9) { 
                       Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
}

var msg = Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec ;
}

var size = 24;

var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;

var letter_spacing = 5;

var diameter = 10;

var rotation = 0.4;
var speed = 0.3;


if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;

msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

mouse = function(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
 xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
},

makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning
 if(init.nopy){
  o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
  o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
 };
 currStep -= rotation;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
  d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
  d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
  d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
 };
},

drag = function(){ // makes the resistance

var birthday = new Date(1917, 3, 8);
var isBirthDay = false;

if((new Date().getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && (new Date().getDate() == birthday.getDate())) {
    var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
    var msg="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳"+"の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう！！！！！";
    isBirthDay = true;

} else {

  var ti = new Date;

     var Hour = ti.getHours();
     var Min = ti.getMinutes();
     var Sec = ti.getSeconds();

        if(Hour <= 9) { 
                       Hour = "\u0020\u0020" + Hour; 
}        
　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                       Min = "0" + Min; 
}
        if(Sec <= 9) { 
                       Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
}

var msg = Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec ;
}

msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1;
for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i)
{
    var elm = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i);
    elm.innerHTML = msg[i];
};

 y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
 x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
 for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
  y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
  x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
 };
 makecircle();
},

init = function(){ // appends message divs, & sets initial values for positioning arrays
 if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
  ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
  xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 } else init.nopy = true;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
  d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
  oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
 };
 o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
 setInterval(drag, 25);
},

ascroll = function(){
 ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
 xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
};

o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

if (window.addEventListener){
 window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
  if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
 window.attachEvent('onload', init);
 document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
};

})();

// -->
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="black">

</body>
</html>
```

追記)以下のコードできちんと分離されるはずですが、elseの表示(奇数の分の場合)のとき、
　　　　ifの表示と合併されて表示されます。理由が分かる方は、教えていただけませんか。

```
～中略～
var birthday = new Date(1917, 3, 8);
var isBirthDay = false;

if((new Date().getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && (new Date().getDate() == birthday.getDate())){

var date = new Date;
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
 var   isBirthDay = true;

  if(minutes%2==0){

    var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
    var msg="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳"+"の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう！！！！！"+" ";

} else {

  var ti = new Date;

     var Hour = ti.getHours();
     var Min = ti.getMinutes();
     var Sec = ti.getSeconds();

        if(Hour <= 9) { 
                       Hour = "\u0020\u0020" + Hour; 
}        
　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                       Min = "0" + Min; 
}
        if(Sec <= 9) { 
                       Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
}

var msg = Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec ;

}
}
～中略～
```

Answer (score 1):

いずれのIFも既に質問者様内のコードにて使用されているので、回答のポイントがずれているかもしれませんが。

```
var date = dt.getDate();
var minutes = dt.getMinutes();
```

で分が取得できますので
minutes%2==0で判定すればよいかと思います。

ページアクセス時の初期メッセージを切り替えるということではなく、
ユーザーがページに1分以上とどまった際にメッセージを切り替えるということであれば

```
var handler = function(){
    //メッセージ切り替え処理
} 
setInterval(handler, 60000);
```

で定期実行されます。

---

殴り書きコードですが、下記で試したらば動作いたしました。
「きちんと機能しませんでした」とは具体的にどういう症状になっているのでしょうか？
各ブラウザには検証ツールがついておりますので、Consoleのエラーログ等でご教示頂けると皆さん回答しやすいかと思います。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  changeMsg = function () {
    var date = new Date;
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var elm = document.getElementById("text");
    if(minutes%2==0){

//前処理省略のため一旦除外          var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
          var age = "dummy"
      var msg="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳"+"の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう！！！！！"+" ";

    } else {

      var ti = new Date;
      var Hour = ti.getHours();
      var Min = ti.getMinutes();
      var Sec = ti.getSeconds();

      if(Hour <= 9) { 
        Hour = "\u0020\u0020" + Hour; 
      }
      if(Min <= 9) { 
        Min = "0" + Min; 
      }
      if(Sec <= 9) { 
                         Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
      }
      var msg = Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec ;

    }
    elm.firstChild.nodeValue =msg
    setInterval(changeMsg,1000);
  }
  window.onload = changeMsg;

</script>
<body>
    <p id="text">test</p>
</body>
```

Comment: minutes%2==0で判定は試したのですが、きちんと機能しませんでした。また、このコード内でfunction()を加えると、表示されなくなります。

Comment: 回答欄に補足コードを記載いたしました。「きちんと機能しませんでした」とは具体的にどういう症状になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問のコードは、即時関数でくくられているためか、その中に"changeMsg = function () {}"を入れると表示されなくなるのです。「きちんと機能しませんでした」とは、追記に加えました。

Comment: 即時関数で括られているのと「%演算子が機能しない」は無関係かと思います。ご提示のコードでもdragの箇所で事実ハンドラ処理が出来ております。また奇数分/偶数分の呼び分け処理も1分ごとの表示切替もできております。

Comment: dragのあたりに私の回答相当の処理を(drag内の処理に合わせて)追加すればご期待の動作になります。ご提示のコードの時点で技術要件揃っており、ノウハウ不足ということはないように見えますので、単純なコーディングミスでうまくいってないのかと思います。各ブラウザの検証機能等を使い、処理がどのように動いているのか1ステップづつ確認しながらコーディングされたほうがよろしいかと思います。余談ですが、ご提示のコードはインデントがあっていなかったり全角スペースが混在していたりで{}の整合性がわかりづらい状態となっております。コーディングミスを誘発するのでインデントのレベルはそろえたほうがよろしいかと思います。